# org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: No ServletContext set

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, jetty

I am trying to enable SpringMVC in an application. The application has legacy code and the integration of Spring is quite difficult. I have a main class called `HttpServerRunner`. In the init method of this class i am calling `initSpringContext` which is giving me a new instance of root spring context.
Now, if i am adding `@EnableWebMvc` configuration, the old method `initSpringContex` throws `No ServletContext set`. It seems that `servletContext` property from `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` is null. I mention that `HttpServerRunner`, the main class, is not a spring class. I think i call `new ApplicationContex`t too earlier, or something like this. If i remove `@EnableWebMvc` configuration i can use RestControllers but i cant return an object using Jackson.

```
SpringConfiguration
```

is the class holding all the beans from my application:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.netoptics", "com.whitelist.manager", "com.websilicon", "com.wsnms.server", "com.anue", "com.wsnms"})
public class SpringConfiguration {

    @Bean
    ......

    @Bean
    .....

        @Bean
        ......

        @Bean
        .....

        @Bean

    }
```

SpringWebConfiguration is the class for spring-mvc:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"com"})
public class SpringWebConfiguration {
}
```

HttpServerRunner, the non-spring class where i am trying to init SpringConfiguration context:

```java
public class HttpServerRunner implements WsHttpServerUpdateable {
    private ApplicationContext springAppContext;

private void initSpringAppContext() {
        this.springAppContext = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SpringConfiguration.class);
    }

 }

private void init(String[] args) throws Throwable { 
WsObjectRegistry.replaceInstance(RedundancyListener.class, DatabaseReplication.getInstance());
        initSpringAppContext();

        initHttpServer();
}
```

So, in the init method i need to have `SpringConfiguration` context loaded for taking beans.

Error i received in `initSpringAppContext`:

```
Caused By: BeanCreationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
```

I i enter on debug mode in `WebMvcConfigurationSuport`, the `servletContext` property is null

web.xml

```xml
<servlet>
            <servlet-name>springMvc</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
                <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>com.netoptics.server.SpringWebConfiguration</param-value>
            </init-param>
        </servlet>


    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.netoptics.server.SpringConfiguration</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springMvc</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/v2/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: What happens if you switch the order of `initSpringAppContext(); initHttpServer();` to  `initHttpServer(); initSpringAppContext();`?

Comment: Web components require a `WebApplicationContext` to function properly. The `WebApplicationContext` requires a `ServletContext`. So in short you are using the wrong `ApplicationContext` in  your code to bootstrap a web related context. Another thing you are actuyally loading the same configuration 3 times. Don't. You are basically loading your application 3 times with this.

Comment: @M.Deinum where should i modify. In the initSpringContext ?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt, yes, but same error

Comment: For starters stop loading it 3 times. Also why do you need to instantiate the context in your `HttpServerRunner ` if everything is already bootstrapped through the `web.xml`.